# WASM+UDF in ScyllaDB, test the performance of WASM

Tags: user-defined-functions, webassembly, fibonacci, scylla

I want to test the performance of WASM in ScyllaDB.While I use the Fibonacci(n=50),showing

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="UDF error: Calling wasm function failed: Trap: wasm trap: all fuel consumed by WebAssembly"
```

In order to test the performance,I need to set the N to a large integer, but it will be out of the range of **i64**.If there any ways to solve the problem about **i64**? Or any other ways to test the performance?

I can get the results of Fibonacci(n=40). And I have tried the Factorial function with the same question.
I'd like to get a comparison of execution speed between Fibonacci(n=50),Fibonacci(n=500),Fibonacci(n=5000)

Comment: I didn't understand why you need to have specifically the fibonacci function. Can't you write a different function, which doesn't grow as large as the fibonacci function, and doesn't exceed the range of i64?
Additionally, what "performance" are you trying to test, actually? The performance of a very slow and very elaborate UDF on a single input? Why is this interesting? Or maybe the performance adding a UDF or UDA over Scylla's ordinary operations?

Comment: The aim for this is to test the performance of WASM in DBMS, compare WASM with the native machine. I can’t think of any other better functions, can you give me any questions? Best wishes!

Comment: So you mean you want to compare the raw performance of WASM code and its interpreter to hand-written C code? Again, I don't know how much of a real problem this is for DBMS (do you often run very long functions in the DB?) but if it is, go for it :-) You can choose whatever function you want that doesn't compute large numbers. I don't have any specific function to recommend.